# What is the IntelliJ shortcut key to insert the tag code in a javadoc comment?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I would like to have a fast way to format text as code while I am writing a comment. In Javadoc to format text as code you must include text inside a `{@code … }` tag. However, it is a little bit tedious to type braces and then @ and after that the text. So it would be nice if there was a shortcut key to achieve it more quickly.

What is the simplest way in IntelliJ to insert a `{@code .... }` in a javadoc comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new *surround* Live Template with an abbreviation you can remember (e.g. `S` for source code). Description something like `Surround with {@code ...}`. Template text: `{@code $SELECTION$}`. Applicable in `Java | Comment`.

Now you can select any text you want to surround with {@code ...} and invoke `Code | Surround With...` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> followed by <kbd>your abbreviation</kbd>) to format it.

Answer (score 2):

I've already noticed that there's already a tutorial how to generate JavaDoc reference for a Project, which tells, that:

> #### To generate project documentation
>
> 1. On the main menu, choose Tools | Generate JavaDoc. Generate JavaDoc
>      dialog is opened.
> 2. In the Generate JavaDoc dialog, specify the following options:
>
>    - Select scope (whole project or a certain project
>        with subpackages).
>    - Specify the output directory, where the generated documentation will be placed.
>    - Use the slider to define the level of visibility of members to be included in the generated documentation.
> 3. Specify the other JavaDoc options. Refer to the topic Generate
>      JavaDoc Dialog for description of controls.
> 4. Click OK.
>
> From: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/generating-javadoc-reference-for-a-project.html

but in mentioned [`Generate JavaDoc Dialog`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/generate-javadoc-dialog.html) there's no `{@code .... }` scope provided...

> What is the simplest way in IntelliJ to insert a {@code .... } in a javadoc comment?

I think the easiest way would be creating live template to later use.

Just go to `Settings -> Live Templates`, choose `Templates Group`, create `JAVADOC` templates group, then add yours JavaDoc `code` template.

Hope it will help

Comment: Maybe my question is not completely clear, yet my problem is not related with Javadoc generation, but with writing Javadoc instead. In particularly, I would like to have a fast way to format text as code while I am writing a comment. In Javadoc to format text as code you must include text inside a `{@code … }` tag. However, it is a little bit dispendious to type braces and then @ and after that the text. So, it would be nice if there was a shortcut key to achieve it more quickly.